# TPageControl not changing tabs when clicked

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-11-alexandria

I have this weird situation that happens usually once every day.

I'm using Delphi 11 on a Windows 11 machine with a Core i9 13th and 40gb of RAM.

I work everyday developing, compiling, linking, and so on.

But, out of nowhere, when I run any of my applications, no matter if inside of the IDE or outside, the `TPageControl`s stop responding to clicks to change their tabs. When this situation happens, the only 'fix' is to reboot or log off and log on again the user in the machine.

I recorded a video to clarify:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=25i6DNpRb4E

Note that the `TPageControl` has 3 tabs: `TabSheet1`, `TabSheet2`, and `TabSheet3`, each one with one `TPanel` inside : `Panel1`, `Panel2`, and `Panel3`.  When I try to change the tabs, it won't change to the content of other tabs, it gets stuck on the content of `Tabsheet1`, which is `Panel1`.

This usually happens every day. It's very annoying because I need to reboot my machine at least once per day. Once I reboot, everything goes back to normal.

Any ideas about what I can look for to fix this?

PS : Usually when i try to reboot the machine, i always get the error below and have to click on 'Restart anyway' to proceed.

[image]

Comment: (1) I trust it won't help to use the keyboard instead of clicking (left and right arrows when the tabs are focused, or (Shift+)Ctrl+Tab when a control on a sheet is focused)? (2) If you move to a page and nothing happens, and you minimize and restore your application, does the right page appear then? (3) If you have windows controls on the new (invisible) page, can you click them or navigate to them? Do they suddenly appear then? (4) Are you using VCL styles? (5) Does this only happen on a particular computer? (Try to run the EXE on a different machine.)

Comment: Are you experiencing any other problems like the ones mentioned in [Delphi Application - Not responding to Click And Draw not Correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77881038/3636228). This might be just a coincidence. But two people reporting similar problems in short time makes me think that there might be some common cause

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand 1/2/3, i'll need to the problem to happen again to test. 4 - No, in the example of the video, it's a simple app without themes. 5 - It happens in several computers, mine and some of my customers , for instance

Comment: Do you really need to "_reboot_" the whole system? It's not enough to close Delphi? It's not enough to log off Windows? It has nothing to do with themes?

Comment: Does it help if you put TabSheet1.HandleNeeded, TabSheet2.HandleNeeded, etc.. in the FormCreate event?

Comment: @AmigoJack  The problem happens if i run the app outside Delphi, so it won't help just to close and open Delphi. About logoff / logon, will test next time

Comment: Wait: is it even a local system we're speaking about? Not a remote system you're controlling through a client which might not be that accurate visually?

Comment: @AmigoJack I'm talking about my own developing machine. But the same issue happens often with my customers running my apps

Comment: Today the issue happened again and this time i tried not to reboot, but just logoff and logon again to Windows , and it FIXES the issue just like the reboot did.