How to avoid TPagecontrol stopping to work after a while
I have this weird situation that happens usually once every day.
I'm using Delphi 11 on a Windows 11 machine with a Core i9 13th and 40gb of RAM.
I work everyday developing, compiling, linking, and so on.
But, out of nowhere, when I run any of my applications, no matter if inside of the IDE or outside, the TPageControls stop responding to clicks to change their tabs. When this situation happens, the only 'fix' is to reboot or log off and log on again the user in the machine.
I recorded a video to clarify:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=25i6DNpRb4E
Note that the TPageControl has 3 tabs: TabSheet1, TabSheet2, and TabSheet3, each one with one TPanel inside : Panel1, Panel2, and Panel3. When I try to change the tabs, it won't change to the content of other tabs, it gets stuck on the content of Tabsheet1, which is Panel1.
This usually happens every day. It's very annoying because I need to reboot my machine at least once per day. Once I reboot, everything goes back to normal.
Any ideas about what I can look for to fix this?

Please add a [mre] in your post. Don't expect anybody here to visit other sites to see your problem.

I'm pretty sure you have asked this exact question previously at SO (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77915721/tpagecontrol-not-changing-tabs-when-clicked?noredirect=1).

@delphirules: You need to debug. Create a brand new VCL app with a page control and a few pages. Compile it, and call it myapp.exe. Then give the source code to some other Delphi developer not related to you or your company and ask him or her to compile it, giving theirapp.exe. Then try both myapp.exe and theirapp.exe on your machine and on the other person's machine. This way you'll find out if you maybe have some third-party add-on in your Delphi IDE or something strange is happening on your computer.

I suspect there is something strange on your computer. If you take a problematic EXE and run it on someone else's computer, do you still observe the problem? If not, we know the problem isn't a Delphi one but something strange on your machine. Have you installed any strange software on your Windows PC, like third-party theming or UX customisation tools?

@AndreasRejbrand Yes but the question was deleted, that's why i'm asking again.

@AndreasRejbrand This issue happens not only on my computer, but on my customer's computers also. It's a matter of time, it will always happen, sometimes on the same day, sometimes the day after

@delphirules: Okay, so probably not related to the system running the EXE. Something strange about the EXE itself. Does this really happen in a brand new and otherwise empty VCL app (as appears to be the case in the video you posted)? Does it happen also if you give the source code of the exact same demo app to some other developer to build on their (completely different) machine?

Do you have events active for the TPageControl or the TTabsheets (TTabSheet.OnShow comes to mind....)?

@AndreasRejbrand I have many apps and many EXE,  and all of them are affected. I've been plagued by this issue for years now and really don't have a solution , just logoff and logon. Really curious about what is happening

@JanDoggen not really

@TomBrunberg i wish but as the issue happens only after a couple of days, it's impossible :-(

Does it also happen in an EXE made on my machine (and, more importantly, my Delphi installation)? Try https://privat.rejbrand.se/pagectl.zip

"but the question was deleted, that's why i'm asking again" There was a reason for the deletion. Posting the same question again will not fix that

@JanDoggen I don't think it was a fair delete. My question is legit and i'm really seeking for help. SO is kind of toxic nowadays

@delphirules I disagree with the toxic - I think it is a more a matter of the site(s) being so large and busy that 'us' old folks are critical on Q&A quality - which is exactly what makes SE sites so valuable. I recently got two of my questions closed as dupes too - I shluld have done more research first, I guess.
